# Android - Application wide notifications

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

What I am looking for is a good example (if possible) of a application wide notification alert dialog window. What I am hoping to do is register an intent filter on the application level, and anytime a broadcast is received, it will show my alert above any fragment, or activity in my application.

Right now I am having to implement it on each activity, while not a big deal seems messy, I was hoping there was a better way.

I had tried to do it once before in the application but the AlertDialog requires the activity context and not the application context.

Thanks
Brian

Comment: You could recieve it in your application http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: I've previously achieved this by declaring a broadcast receiver in a base class from which all my activities are derived.

Comment: thanks, I created an abstract class which extends the activity class.

Comment: @bhawkins I've copied my comment to an answer so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've previously achieved this by declaring a broadcast receiver in a base class from which all my activities are derived.